# How can I check if an email is verified in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, swift4

So I'm trying to check in firebase if an email is verified. There is no documentation for swift in the google docs and everything online is outdated to.

Comment: The question is unclear - you're trying to check it from where? The app? The Firebase console? By that user or another user? When you state there's no [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users) and it's [outdated](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes), what do you mean?  It looks pretty current to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send an email to [verify the user's email address](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email):

> ```
> Auth.auth().currentUser?.sendEmailVerification { (error) in
>   // ...
> }
> ```

To check if the [email address was verified](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/User#isemailverified):

```
if Auth.auth().currentUser?.isEmailVerified {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks the second part of the code was what I was looking for.